# how select multiple elements from a tuple by several types in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, stdtuple

Here is my code, `a` is supposed to get a variable of type `std::tuple<int,bool>`. But, it does not work. So, what is wrong and how to fix it?

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

template <class... Ts>
class vector_df {
public:
    std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...> data;

    template <class... As>
    auto select() {
        return std::make_tuple(std::get<As>(data)...);
    }
};

int main() {
    vector_df<int,char,bool> df;
    auto a = df.select<int,bool>();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the code link on an online C++ IDE. https://godbolt.org/z/BwzvCZ
The Error Message:

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/tuple: In instantiation of 'constexpr _Tp& std::get(std::tuple<_Elements ...>&) [with _Tp = int; _Types = {std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >, std::vector<bool, std::allocator<bool> >}]':

<source>:11:38:   required from 'auto vector_df<Ts>::select() [with As = {int, bool}; Ts = {int, char, bool}]'

<source>:17:34:   required from here

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.1.0/include/c++/9.1.0/tuple:1365:37: error: no matching function for call to '__get_helper2<int>(std::tuple<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >, std::vector<bool, std::allocator<bool> > >&)'

 1365 |     { return std::__get_helper2<_Tp>(__t); }

      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

Comment: *But, it does not work.* <-- Include the error message in your question along with expected and actual behaviour if relevant.

Comment: `std::make_tuple(std::get<std::vector<As>>(data)...);` or `df.select<std::vector<int>,std::vector<bool>>();`.

Comment: You have `std::vector<Ts>...` in your tuple but trying to get `int` and `bool` from it.

Answer (score 3):

```
 auto a = df.select<int,bool>();
```

Your parameters to this template function are `int` and `bool`.

But it's obvious that your `data` tuple contains `std::vector`s of them, so your `select()` method should be:

```
template <class... As>
auto select() {
    return std::make_tuple(std::get<std::vector<As>>(data)...);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution works. I have spent 4 hours to find the bug. Thank you very much.